# How to properly create figures (such as coordinate system) in Tikz in a timely manner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, coordinates

I am new to LaTex and Tikz Package. I am trying to create figures in Tikz (which was recommended to me in my previous question). This is what I had made after days of tinkering. However, I made this figure for two days, which is time-consuming. I am wondering if there is a better way to do it? And what are the essential things to keep in mind when creating figures? **I can't seem to understand what is going on.** I highly appreciate any guidance given to me.

**Code:**

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.7]

%Coordinate System
\draw[-{Latex[width'=5pt 0, length=5pt]}] (-5,0) -- (5,0); 
\draw[-{Latex[width'=5pt 0, length=5pt]}] (0,-5) -- (0,5);

%Angle
\coordinate (A) at (5,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (176:5) ;
\draw [-{Latex[width'=5pt 0, length=5pt]}] (0,0) -- (176:5);

%Arrow
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)
pic [draw=black, angle radius=30mm] {angle = A--B--C};


%Angle
\coordinate (A) at (176:5);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (180:5);

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)
pic [fill=green!25, draw=black, angle radius=30mm] {angle = A--B--C};
%Label
\draw (-3,-0.3) node [fill=white!100!black, scale=1]
{$4^{\circ}$};

\draw (0,3) node [fill=white!100!black, scale=1]
{$176 ^{\circ}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Illustration of $176 ^{\circ}$ with its reference angle}
\label{fig:176}
\end{figure}
```

**Output:**

[image: My own figure]

This is the figure that I really wanted to create. It is from a paper by **King et al. (2020)** titled "Trigonometry: a brief conversation."

[image: What I wanted]

King, C., Evelyn, T., Ye, F., & Carvajal, B. (2020). Trigonometry: A Brief Conversation. Open Educational Resources. https://academicworks.cuny.edu/qb_oers/167/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: As with all powerfull tools, it takes time to learn. This site is for concise questions that can be answered. I can not figure out what your question is!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values of angles written by `quotes` (on usual way) does not given very pleasant result. In this particular case seems to be more appropriate add them separately outside of `pic` macro. For example, as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
               > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
every pin/.style = {pin edge={<-,black}, font=\footnotesize},
 my angle/.style = {draw, <->,
                    angle radius = 30mm,
                    angle eccentricity=0.6,
                    font=\scriptsize}
                       ]
% coordinate system
\draw[-Stealth] (-4,0) coordinate (A')
                 -- (4,0) coordinate (A);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
% coordinates
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (176:4) ;
% vector
\draw[->, semithick]   (B) -- (C);
% Angle 4 degree
\pic [my angle, fill=green!25] {angle = C--B--A'};
\coordinate[pin=300:\qty{4}{\degree}] (aux)   at (178:2.8);
% Angle 176 degree
\pic [my angle] {angle = A--B--C};
\node   at (135:2.4) {\qty{176}{\degree}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the second image in your MWE, angle values write by use `quotes` package, gives nice rezult:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
               > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
every pin/.style = {pin edge={<-,black}, font=\footnotesize},
 my angle/.style = {draw, <->,
                    angle radius = 30mm,
                    angle eccentricity=1.1,
                    font=\scriptsize}
                       ]
% coordinate system
\draw[-Stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0) coordinate (A);
\draw[-Stealth] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
% coordinates
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (240:4) ;
% vector
\draw[->, semithick]   (B) -- (C);
% Angle 240 degree
\pic [my angle, "\qty{240}{\degree}"] {angle = A--B--C};
% Angle 120 degree
\pic [my angle, "\qty{120}{\degree}"] {angle = C--B--A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like very much your job for the angle.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much!

Comment: @Zarko, thank you so much for your response and effort. I finished the 2nd part of my homework just now, thanks to you. Very well-done and perfectly made.

Comment: @AidreCabrera, you are welcome. I'm glad to know, that someone use LaTeX for writing of homework :-)